# Having more spreadsheets displayed in the recent opened list in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I'm currently using Excel 2003. The list of recently opened spreadsheets accessed through the File menu contains the last four opened and edited spreadsheets.

Is it possible to change the number of spreadsheets displayed, so that it can display for instance the last 10 spreadsheets opened in this menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools->Options->General -> Recently used file list